# Why only one background image is not visible on iPhone only?

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone

I was working with [this website](https://info.nphoto.com/en/wedding-sample-guide-ebook).
And I've noticed a really strange thing. In the footer, there's this section 'why nphoto' and [the very last image](https://i.imgur.com/aVZulwP.png) in it is not visible on iPhone only. Despite having exactly the same styling as the rest. I'm puzzled here. And I have no way of debugging iOS.
Please help.

Comment: just checked on my phone (iphone 12). image is visible both on chrome and safari

Comment: Hi Ricky, thank you for checking this. I was using appetize.io for my preview. https://i.imgur.com/BgV7vee.png